upload files to external wordpress website
I have two wordpress websites
I need that when I upload any file in the first website, it will be uploaded to the second website
I've created an endpoint for file uploads in the second website in this location
https://my_second_site.com/wprt/upload.php:
<?php
// Your WordPress site URL should point to this file for uploads
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php');

if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    $uploadedfile = $_FILES['file'];

    $upload_overrides = ['test_form' => false];

    $movefile = wp_handle_upload($uploadedfile, $upload_overrides);

    if ($movefile && !isset($movefile['error'])) {
        echo json_encode([
            'success' => true,
            'url' => $movefile['url'],
            'size' => filesize($movefile['file'])
        ]);
    } else {
        echo json_encode(['success' => false, 'error' => $movefile['error']]);
    }
} else {
    echo json_encode(['success' => false, 'error' => 'No file uploaded.']);
}

then in the first website I read the submitted files by this code :
 if (isset($_FILES['files'])) {
        $files = $_FILES['files'];
        $file_names = isset($_POST['file_names']) ? $_POST['file_names'] : [];
        $uploaded_files = [];

        // Loop through each file
        foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $name) {
            $file_info = [
                'name' => $files['name'][$key],
                'type' => $files['type'][$key],
                'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$key],
                'error' => $files['error'][$key],
                'size' => $files['size'][$key]
            ];

            // Use cURL to upload file to the second site
            $ch = curl_init();
            $cfile = new CURLFile($file_info['tmp_name'], $file_info['type'], $file_info['name']);
            $data = [
                'file' => $cfile,
                'file_name' => $file_names[$key]
            ];

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://my_second_site.com/wprt/upload.php'); // Update this URL
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            $response = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);

            $response_data = json_decode($response, true);

            // If upload is successful, add file information to uploaded_files array
            if (isset($response_data['success']) && $response_data['success']) {
                $uploaded_files[] = [
                    'url' => $response_data['url'],
                    'size' => $response_data['size'],
                    'name' => $file_names[$key]
                ];
            }
        }

        // If there are uploaded files, send success response, otherwise send error
        if (!empty($uploaded_files)) {
            wp_send_json_success($uploaded_files);
        } else {
            wp_send_json_error(['error' => 'File upload failed.']);
        }
    }

but the uploading is failed
what do I have to fix here please ?

And what errors you get?
